# how to handle lack of shape normalization in no-sql databases

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, nosql

I’m working with a firebase database. I’ve been assigned as task: convert all timestamp objects that get returned from the database to Date objects.

I’m not that familiar with no-sql databases like firebase. But I know what the shape of the data is not normalized across all records. This poses a problem for me that I wouldn’t have to worry about in a SQL database.
Whereas in a SQL database, if one record came back with no timestamp, I can guarantee that no records from the same table will have timestamps. But this is not guaranteed for a no-sql database like firebase.

So if a record came back looking like this:

```
{
id: 123,
name: George Smith,
age: 42
}
```

How do I know a different record won’t come back looking like this:

```
{
id: 123,
name: George Smith,
age: 42,
createdDate: {…}
updatedDate: {…}
}
```

Give the task I’ve been assigned (convert timestamps to Date objects), how does a developer handle cases like this?

I’m developing in Angular/Typescript

Comment: In very general terms, there's no guarantee a field in SQL will contain (valid) data - that guarantee is up to the developer and defined via the table schema. Suppose there's an SQL table that stores timestamps as strings. As queried rows are read from a table, one of the rows that's supposed to have a timestamp string is populated with 'Hello, World'. Well, you need to have code to account for that - either on the front end to guarantee valid data is written and/or the back end to handle when data is invalid. Firebase (or any I/O system) is the same GIGO (Garbage In/ Garbage Out).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, "shapeless" nosql doesn't imply that you can't make assumptions about what's in each record.  Code can be written to ensure that only valid and complete data is written, and that allows you to make assumptions about the data when it's read.  That's the first best way to handle things.

But if you absolutely must assume that any field in any record may be a timestamp, you'll have to write code that recursively descends the properties for each record, looking for objects that look like timestamps, and converting them all as needed.  You could tell if an object is a timestamp by checking that it has a toDate method to call.

Comment: In fact, I would argue that Firebase may be schemaless, most implementations are definitely not shapeless. There is a very clear structure on most data structures.

Comment: I would like to add that Firebase only contains what is put in it (sounds like a Vulcan proverb). When developing an app there would be code that writes to the database so generally, you would have some knowledge or control of what the writing possibilities are and can account for situations where data doesn't exist to what @dougstevenson mentioned. There are times when you may be coding in a vacuum so best practice is to always watch for and handle non-existent data in the same way, every time (i.e. be consistent) Just my .02.